# Why are there next AND previous paging URLs in the initial response from a Facebook Graph query?

Tags: facebook, api

Why would there be a next AND previous link in the original search results?

Say for example:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=car&type=post&access_token=...

At the end of the first page of results you are able to page backwards and forwards? I would have expected to just go forwards then the next result page should have both previous and next.

...]
, "paging": {

"previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=car&type=post&access_token=...", 
"next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=car&type=post&access_token=..." 
}

Answer (score 1):

The next and previous on the initial query allows you to at a later time use the links to query the server for newer data then you had previously gotten.

This way you can request ONLY the new data, and have to parse ONLY the new data, and then you can elegantly shove the new data in with the already existing data that you had previously received.

This i presume is why they use a time stamp in the next and previous links as well instead of an offset.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What you say would make sense - except that up until now I have actually only been using the 'next' paging links to get all the historical data for a feed and hadn't even used the 'previous' links.

The 'next' links already had pages worth of data in. So I am still confused, but maybe I am not following you correctly.

Comment: I think are not following correctly.

You get a next and previous on all feed queries. If you look at the previous link data you'll notice that it has a 'since' field it passes along. This gets all feed data SINCE that time, which would be any new posts that were not there the last time you queried the feed and ONLY new ones.

The next link is used to grab Posts farther down the list (farther back in time) then the posts you have currently queried. This allows you to handle the data on your own and dynamically update the visual display of the lists with minimal overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this Jason - I'm still not clear though :-/ I wanted to post some sample results here with further explanation but I am only allowed 440 more characters..

You mentioned:
'The next link is used to grab Posts farther down the list (farther back in time) then the posts you have currently queried'

But for me it seems the 'previous' links which are doing this. (I said earlier that the 'next' links have pages worth of data but actually these only had a few days worth whereas the previous links see to go on indefinitely into the past.